# C++ #define that gets a string

Tags: c++, obfuscation, xor, pre-compilation

I want to create a VERY basic obfuscation method, basically I just wanna `xor` every string so calling

```
printf("%s\n", OBF("Test"));
```

Will generate something like

```
printf("%s\n", unxor("\x65\x54\x42\x45"));
```

I xored the string with `1` in this case

Comment: I don't think there's any way to loop over a string in the preprocessor.

Comment: Write a function.

Comment: Might be able to pull something off with [preprocessor metaprogramming](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't use printf in C++

Comment: no idea why people saying it can't be done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981003/8874953

Comment: so, then: Possible duplicate of [C++: How to encrypt strings at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102320/c-how-to-encrypt-strings-at-compile-time)

Answer (score 1):

Using modern C++ you can write it without any macros like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

constexpr const char key_byte{'1'};

template<::std::size_t VArrayItemsCount, ::std::size_t... Is> constexpr auto
obf_impl
(
    ::std::index_sequence<Is...>
,   char const ( & sz_text )[VArrayItemsCount]
)
-> ::std::array<char, VArrayItemsCount>
{
    return(::std::array<char, VArrayItemsCount>{static_cast<char>(sz_text[Is] ^ key_byte)..., '\0'});
}

template<::std::size_t VArrayItemsCount> constexpr auto
obf
(
    char const ( & sz_text )[VArrayItemsCount]
)
-> ::std::array<char, VArrayItemsCount>
{
    return
    (
        obf_impl<VArrayItemsCount>
        (
            ::std::make_index_sequence<VArrayItemsCount - ::std::size_t{1}>()
        ,   sz_text
        )
    );
}

int main()
{
    constexpr const auto hello{obf("hello")};
    ::std::cout << hello.data() << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Run this code in online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vWDrQy5q5bW8BVFD)