# How can I obfuscate an EXE file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, obfuscation

I have an EXE file. It comes from a Qt C++ Visual Studio project.
I would like to obfuscate this EXE.
The main reason is that my URLs (for version files, API etc.) that I use in the program and any other strings can be easily edited with a HeX editor.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might be interested in [C++: How to encrypt strings at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4102320/10077).

Comment: So there is no way to do it without code change?

Comment: None that I know of.

Comment: Here's another one: [techniques for obscuring sensitive strings in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1648618/10077). Might give you some more ideas.

Comment: Look up the EXE file format.  You may be able to add a program to your executable that decrypts the data.  However, be prepared for your program to slow to a crawl.

Comment: It might be sufficient to use a Exe packer like this: https://upx.github.io/

Comment: This task is fairly futile. No matter how much you obfuscate/encrypt the strings in the EXE, at some point at runtime you are going to have to unobfuscate/decrypt the strings in order to use them, and a dedicated hacker will simply wait for your app to do that and then modify the URLs in memory before they are used.

Comment: I just want to hide my strings because now it’s easy to edit with a HeX editor. UPX packer can do this? Or Themida would be better? It’s  a little bit expensive for me to protect only one program. How others do it? (Protect API, version file URL etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used UPX packer and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily reverse UPX Packer. With the `-d` Option!

Semantic Design might be interesting.

For DLLs you can try: [Free Obfuscator](https://freeobfuscator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Eziriz .NET Reactor](https://www.eziriz.com/) seems to do a good job of obfuscating dll files and it will combine them.

Limitation is it will not function on `.exe` files, only `.net` files.